# Having problems graphing a plotly line chart instead of scatter

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have created a shiny application that has a drop down to select items.  The current code looks like this:

```
#Import libraries
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)

# Define UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "n_breaks",
              label = "Select Item:",
              choices = c("item1", "item2", "item3"),
              selected = "Item1"),
 plotlyOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "600px")
 )

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

#Import data
df = read.csv("data/Items.csv")
#Flip data around
df2 <- df %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -(time:flex_string_2)) %>% 
    unite(temp, flex_string_2, variable) %>% 
    group_by(temp) %>% 
    mutate(id=1:n()) %>% 
    spread(temp, value) 
#Remove the id column
df2 <- subset(df2, select = -c(id))
#Remove "_extra_stuff_on_end" from titles
names(df2) = gsub(pattern = "_extra_stuff_on_end*", replacement = "", x = 
names(df2)) 
#Convert to dataframe
df3 <- as.data.frame(df2)
#Convert factor to datetime
df3$time <- as.character.POSIXt(df3$time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  

output$main_plot <- renderPlotly({

plot_ly(df3, x = ~time, 
        y = df3[, input$n_breaks],
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines',
        color = df3[, input$n_breaks]) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(type = "category"))

 })   
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The dataframe looks like this 4 columns and 26949 rows:

```
df
      time                      item1    item2    item3
1     2018-04-09 00:00:06        615       NA       NA
2     2018-04-09 00:00:08         NA      465       NA
3     2018-04-09 00:00:08         NA       NA       NA
4     2018-04-09 00:00:10         NA       NA      422
5     2018-04-09 00:00:13         NA       NA       NA
6     2018-04-09 00:00:21        522       NA      385
7     2018-04-09 00:00:25         NA       NA       NA
....  ....                       ....     ....     ...
26949 2018-04-09 23:59:59        323       NA      200
```

When I run this code I get a scatter plot.  I would really like a line graph but when this is ran it is a scatter and I get a warning, "Warning: Numeric color variables cannot (yet) be mapped to lines. when the trace type is 'scatter' or 'scattergl'."

If i remove the:

```
type = 'scatter'
```

I get a bar trace.

Comment: can you add (using `dput`) Items.csv to your post. Otherwise, we can't run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with if else statements that keep the line chart:

```
.... 
#Convert to dataframe
df3 <- as.data.frame(df2)
#Convert factor to datetime
df3$time = strptime(df3$time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


output$main_plot <- renderPlotly({

  if (input$n_breaks == "item1") {
    #Create variable X getting rid of NA values
    x <- df3$time[!is.na(df3$item1)]
    #Convert date to POSIXct for plotly
    x = as.POSIXct(x,format="%Y-%m/%d T %H:%M:%S", tz ="UTC")
    #Create variable Y getting rid of NA values
    y <- df3$item1[!is.na(df3$item1)]
    #Plotly plot
    plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
}
  else if (input$n_breaks == "item2") {
    #Create variable X getting rid of NA values
    x <- df3$time[!is.na(df3$item2)]
    #Convert date to POSIXct for plotly
    x = as.POSIXct(x,format="%Y-%m/%d T %H:%M:%S", tz ="UTC")
    #Create variable Y getting rid of NA values
    y <- df3$item2[!is.na(df3$item2)]
    #Plotly plot
    plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')  
}
  else if (input$n_breaks == "item3") {
    #Create variable X getting rid of NA values
    x <- df3$time[!is.na(df3$item3)]
    #Convert date to POSIXct for plotly
    x = as.POSIXct(x,format="%Y-%m/%d T %H:%M:%S", tz ="UTC")
    #Create variable Y getting rid of NA values
    y <- df3$item3[!is.na(df3$item3)]
    #Plotly plot
    plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')  
  }

  })   
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```